# "Pick up", "gather" or "collect" a person?

Tags: word-choice

A person is coming by airplane and a friend of his is going to meet him and take him to his home. Let's assume we are talking about the UK. Only the two people, a car and an airplane are involved.

Which phrase between *pick up*, *gather*, and *collect* is best and more common to use when referring to meeting people and transporting them somewhere?

Comment: You need to flesh out your context. Who is involved, a limousine driver? A soccer mom?  Who are the people? What is the nature of the "meeting"? Where are you, London or Atlanta?  Without such details, there's no way to say what is "best" or "more common".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the phrasal verb **pick up** which can mean that you will go somewhere to meet someone (usually with some form of transport) and then take them somewhere.

e.g. I have to go the airport to **pick up** my mother.

e.g. I will **pick** you **up** after lunch at your home. (notice we split the phrasal verb).

I have heard the word **collect** used to refer to people being picked up.

e.g. I am going to **collect** the kids from school.

However, I think that collect is used more commonly to refer to objects such as packages.

e.g. I have a package to collect from the post office.

I haven't heard **gathe**r being used for the purpose you describe.

Gather means to bring things or people together.

e.g. Please **gather** all your toys together and put them in the box.

e.g. We need to gather the team together to discuss the game.

Comment: I agree with your “collect the kids from school” example, but I’d add that that’s a pretty informal usage, almost to the point of being lightheartedly humorous. Also, _pick up_ can be used for inanimate objects as well as people: I might well say, “I need to pick up a package a the post office.”